# Is it possible to update props or declare props as var to render sub-component in child component? in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I build parent and child component name `RightFrame`, I want to display different component. so I using state to update child component and pass it as `props`. but I want the child component self can update the state (now props) too. but I know that the rule have to declare `props` as const so It can't update.

the parent component look like:

```
const [page, setpage] = useState();

return(
<button onClick={() => setpage("main")} 
...
<RightFrame page={page}/>
);
```

and `RightFrame` that have 3 sub-component and I want that to update `page` by them self to change `page` (since `EditClass` and `CreateClass` is the component that have action that can be cancel, so after cancel by button and go back to render `Class` by `<button onClick={page = "main"}`)

```
export default function RightFrame(props) {
  const { page } = props;

  return (
  <>
    {page == "main" && <Class/>}
    {page == "edit" && <EditClass/>}
    {page == "new" && <CreateClass/>}
  </>
)
```

and that's the problem that I want to solve, so I don't know that it is possible to declare props as var on not.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the setPage as props so you can use the function to update it.
Example

You can now use setPage in component child